# Java, Close FileWriter changes file MD5 value

Tags: java

I need to create a MD5 file after creating a file with some contents.

But I find a problem that the md5 value of the file is different from the actual file value though I don't change the file itself.

At last I find that if I create the md5 file inside the try-with-resources block, the md5 changes. I wrote below code snippet to verify what I guess

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "D:\\push\\file\\imei2device\\imei2device.txt";
    File f = new File(filePath);
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);){
        fw.write("something");
        //createMD5File(filePath);// create here, NOT OK!

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    createMD5File(filePath);// create here, ok
    logger.info("create md5 file successfully, notModified: {}", MappedFileReader.isFileNotModified(filePath));
}
```

when I put `createMD5File` in two different place , I will find a MD5 value is different.

I suspect that the file itself is different when the FileWriter is close, like the EOF?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no explicit EOF on the disk, you need to wait for the file to finish writing before you try to compute the MD5 with the file contents (that is `flush()` the file before computing the sum). Alternatively, calculate the hash based on the contents you are writing from memory (it'll be faster then rereading the data from disk).

Comment: Thank you! I have another problem , I tried to calculate the MD5 when I am reading the file, but I find the value is different from the value what lib returns, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420069/calculate-file-md5-while-reading-file-by-mappedbytebuffer

Comment: Yes, a single byte difference in input is highly likely to yield a completely different output. The Windows line separator is "\r\n" (not "\n").

Comment: But I tests it in linux and the value is still different.